# Why doesn't Google uninstall or report, installed pirated apps?

Tags: android, legal

Why doesn’t Google do anything about pirated apps? It seems really easy to catch the users.

You could go to a website and download an apk for an app which you normally pay for in the play store. After installing the app, it appears as “installed” when you go to the Google Play app and browse to it’s page, so Google must know you have it installed and would also know you didn’t get it through them…so it seems like a simple conclusion you pirated it. Why doesn’t Google do anything about this? It even allows the pirated app to be updated, which I think happens with through the Google Play service.

I guess one could argue they make it this way so that app owners can sell their product not through the google store, but it still seems like it would be easy for Google to send a message to the owner being like “hey, this guy has your app and he didn’t download it through us” and the owner knows you didn’t download it through them, and then you’re caught.

**TL;DR** Google seems well aware of all apps installed on the phone, and since 99% of the time google is the only source it seems like an easy way to catch pirates. Why is it still so prominent? I’m assuming it has to do with laws.

Comment: Is there anything about **security** in this question?

Comment: Piracy is a game of cat and mouse. If Google implements countermeasures then pirates will implement something to circumvent those. So it's not worth for them to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is an open source system. Its the users choice what to do. If he wants to install pirated apps google will not stop him. If google would, the users would disable google play and youre still not blocking pirated apps.